# Layout nesting problems in Android

Tags: android

I have a scrollview which acts wierd when scrolling. I have to scroll twice before the scrollview starts scrolling. This below is how my nesting is done. Does this nesting look alright, or is it bad? I tried rearranging the layouts but I couldnt stop the "two-time" scrolling problem I have.

**first layout:** (this one is inside a constraint layout)

```
//views before

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/yahoo_view"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cond_const"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            layout="@layout/scroll_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

//views after
```

**Second layout:**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollview3">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/forecast_constraint"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    //all this layout-files views here

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**EDIT:**

[image]

Comment: I presume the second layout is the one being `include`ed? Nested scrolling containers that scroll on the same axis are problematic, unless they support nested scrolling, which regular `ScrollView` does not. Perhaps you can find a cleaner solution, or post an image of what the end result should look like and someone can suggest a more straightforward approach.

Comment: @Karakuri Yes, second layout is the included one. I'm not aiming at having two scrollviews, just one. (beginner here) I added a picture to my post, where I try to draw what Im trying to do. Can you take a look, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe I am misunderstanding, but you want the screen to scroll in both directions?

if not, then don't nest a scrollview inside a scrollview.

Either is probably obsolete.  removing your  for now.

try just

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollview">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/forecast_constraint"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    //all this layout-files views here

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: No, just scroll vertically. Which ScrollView should I delete? Which one's the obsolete?

Comment: updated answer.  I'm presuming you want all your scrolling content in your constraintlayout.  Generally if the whole page should scroll, then the root view should be a scrollview.